# Manage Site Content and Structure in SharePoint 2013 Missing?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I am not able to locate `Manage Site Content and Structure` option on publishing sites in SP 2013. Is it removed?

Comment: It is worth repeating, this config item is only available if the site has the "SharePoint Server Publishing" feature(s) enabled. The OP indicates this is the case, but it is easy to overlook eg in a team site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not removed - just moved to **Site Settings > Site Administration**

[image]

Reference: [Manage content and structure in SharePoint 2013](http://wmostafaw.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/manage-content-and-structure-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: I don't see this option on my system. (I am SCA, but not owner of that SP server.)

Answer (score 18):

The item is no longer in the action menu.

You can reach it from Site Settings --> Content and Structure (under Site Administration)

or via url

```
http://{YOURSITENAME}/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx
```

Comment: IMHO the URL is the only useful straightforward answer to the original question. (The link to "Content and Structure" is not visible for me.) It will always remain a miracle to me, why Microsoft is hiding useful options so well.

Comment: In a similar vein, here is a list of other special urls: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/how24/2013/05/23/famous-sharepoint-urls-locations/

Comment: Sadly it just work with SP Server version. On SP 2013 Foundation this page depends on SharePoint Server Publishing feature, which is not available on SP Foundation.

Comment: Although the OP asked for the version 2013, I've tested, and the same URL works for the versions 2016 and 2019 (on-premise) as well, as long the publishing feature is activated.