# Move sub site content to parent site

Tags: 2013, sub-site, content

I have to move a subsite located at http://sp.abc.com/sites/it/eng to http://sp.abc.com/sites/it

Is there a easy way to move the content over with security.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint On Prem please try this one:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/356985/Moving-a-Sharepoint-Sub-Site-to-its-own-Site-Colle

SharePoint online- The only solution I can advise to you - save site as template, then from solution gallery save to you disk as file, import this solution to another site collection's solution gallery, and recreate site form this new template

Answer (score 1):

For moving/copying contents within a site collection, the easiest and best solution would be to use the manage content and structure option present under the site settings. The link is accessible by following this path.

"Site Settings" -> "Site Administration" -> "Content and Structure"

or you can follow this url directly in your browser "http://sp.abc.com/sites/it/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx"

Here are some other links that can help you.

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-with-site-content-and-structure-30fcaad9-02b1-4347-8b03-e1ccc5a4c19f
- [Manage Site Content and Structure in SharePoint 2013 Missing?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66154/manage-site-content-and-structure-in-sharepoint-2013-missing/66158)