# How to move a file stored in a folder of a document library into the root of that document library (Sharepoint 2013)?

Tags: 2013, document-library, folder, file, move

There are multiple articles, tutorials, and videos on the web that show how to move a file into a folder. However I cannot find references for the opposite scenario.

How to move a file located in a folder into the root folder of the document library?

My interest is from an end-user prespective (basically doing it using the standard interface) not from a programming perspective.

Comment: I guess I had to ask the question to finally find the answer the day after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so, select a file located in a subfolder and drag&drop it onto the Document Library shortcut in the Left Pane.

I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dr794Kzjv4) from European Sharepoint Community that explains very well how to do it.

This video tutorial covers:

- moving a file from the root of Document Library to a subfolder in the same Document Library,
- moving a file from a subfolder in the Document Library to the root of the Document Library,
- moving a file from a subfolder to a different subfolder in the same Document Library.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the [Site Content & Structure tool](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66154/manage-site-content-and-structure-in-sharepoint-2013-missing/66158) that is available under Site Settings.

1. On the Site Content and Structure page, select the item or multiple items to move.
2. Click Actions, and then click Move.
3. In the Move dialog box, select a destination and then click OK.