# Sharepoint 2013 - Move folder to another folder

Tags: 2013, move

Sharepoint 2013 - I have the page, which has document library (named "Library123"). The library has 2 folders (named "Folder1" and "Folder2").
So my question is how do I move "Folder1" with its content to "Folder2"?

What I tried so far is:

- I tried to open document library with the option "Open with Explorer" but I get warning "We're having a problem opening this location in File Explorer. Add this web site to your Trusted Sites list and try again.". I did that (It's under Internet Explorer -> Internet Options -> Security -> Trusted sites and you add the site) but it's showing the same error. I tried to turn off firewall (found while Googling) and bunch other fixes.
- I tried with Internet Explorer 32 & 64 bit, I get the same error
- i tried run Internet Explorer as admin, i get same error

Do I need to hire Sharepoint 2013 special engineer to move single folder to another folder? Am I missing some option? Is it so complicated?

Comment: Are you trying to do it on client computer and browser? Because IE gives same error to me on server, but I can easily use Open With Explorer at IE on clients machine.

Comment: Yes, i am trying it on server, but i also tried on other servers which are only Domain Controller, one is holding on SPS SQL server. I will try on client PC. Nice idea

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

1. Go to **Site Settings**. Under **Site Administration**, you have **Site Content and Structure**
2. Create a folder named "Folder1" inside your destination folder/library.
3. Open your source folder which is "Folder1", **check all** contents and click on **Actions**, from there select **MOVE** and choose your desination folder which is "Folder2".

You don't need any Sharepoint 2013 special engineer for this. :P

Comment: Thanks you so much for answer. I don't have option "Site Content and Structure" under "Site Administration", but i manger to access to the same page via URL http://{YOURSITENAME}/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx Taken from : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/66157/67417

Comment: Sadly i get message "Move is not supported for Lists and Folders" :/

Comment: You should be copying the contents of the folder not the folder it self.

Comment: Hmm, so if i have parent folder "Folder1" with 120 child folders and each of child folder has 10 files/items, you are telling me that i need to create 120 folder manually in my destination folder (recreate same structure), go into each source child folder, select all contents and move it to destination folder which i created previously ?

Comment: Create a folder and then copy all items in it..

Comment: You should have mention you have multiple folders inside your folder in your description..

Comment: Now talking about what you tried, did you try opening the site in explorer from other machines?

Comment: @harshalgite sorry, i wanted to simplify question as much as possible. I tried on some other servers i have in "cloud" but i get same error. I will try to find physical PC with windows and Internet Explorer. Right now i'm on Mac

Comment: Try on windows..

Comment: I believe the "Content and Structure" link requires the Publishing Site Collection Feature to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the windows explorer method. In the event IEx86 is crippled for some reason.
Try opening Windows Explorer and typing a network path in this format:

```
\\\FQDN\sitecollection\subsite
```

For example the browser URL would be: `https://FQDN/mysite/mysubsite`